# Missing material dependencies after upgrade to Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material

I followed the upgrade guide to migrate Angular from 8.2 to 9.1. I am also using Angular material which as per the guide I also updated. I also made sure all other packages are at Wanted version.

Whenever I try to run the solution I get:

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/material/core" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/core
 - @angular/platform-browser
 - rxjs
 - rxjs/operators
 - @angular/platform-browser/animations
 - @angular/common
 - @angular/forms
```

There are no outdated packages as checked with npm outdated.

All angular packages have been updated to the latest with ng update and just to be sure I cleared the cache with `npm cache clear --force`.

The version of @angular/core is at "@angular/core": `"^9.1.11"` and material at `"^9.2.4"`.

I am assuming material depends on a different version of core but don't understand why it would install it by default with ng-cli and what version to install if its not the right one

Comment: I'd blow away the `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` and then `npm install`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work, i get the same error

Comment: Did you try `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk` and then clearing the cache?

Comment: Can you show the output of `npm list --depth=0` ?

Comment: When you say “run the solution” are you using an ide like visual studio? Do you have some kind of non standard way of running the project? Or are you just running npm start from a command line?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the material version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow following steps :-

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. Delete package-lock.json file.
3. Run **npm cache clean --force**
4. Run **npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk**

Then try to run your project.

Comment: This was already done and its mentioned in the question

Comment: @qubits added one more step above.

Comment: @qubits how did you upgrade @angular/material and why the core version mismatches with material?

Comment: We solved this by upgrading directly to Angular 10, seems like some of our dependencies had a version conflict, we weren't able to identify which exactly. This could work however for most people so I will mark it as solution.

Comment: Still facing the same issue after upgrading to angular 10

Answer (score 0):

Try using yarn (version 1, not version 2) https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable.

Yarn has very good compatibility with npm, but uses a completely different module cache folder, and does additional node_modules checks to make sure your modules are in the correct state.

Yarn may not be an entirely satisfactory solution to your problem, however it is not unusual for some people on a project to use yarn, and some to use npm, due to the high compatibility between them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can give some insight:

I had the same problem but in my case the error occured in a package I build i.e. *package X*.

I was able to solve the problem in *package X*  by:

1. **Removing package-lock.json**
2. Running command **npm cache clean --force**
3. Rebuilding package

Then in the project where i wanted to use *package X*:

1. **npm install Package X**

Problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while updating node modules on my project, only the error was in an in-house library that my project consumes. I ended up discovering that Angular was dependent on an older version of rxjs than the library (that I'd just updated). Downgrading rxjs to match what Angular was pulling in resolved the issue for me.